# How can I export images with my apk file in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application for android with eclipse, and it has some logos (.jpg image files) that I reference from my code.

The problem is that, when I export with eclipse the .apk file to install the app, the logos aren't exported...

How can I export the package to have the logos when I install the application?

Thanks!!!

Comment: where yo storing those images in your project?

Comment: In a folder in the root directory of the project. The problem is, that it doesn't export it to the apk file...

Comment: Have you tried adding them to the assets directory instead?

Comment: I don't know how to use this... Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in folder res/drawable, they can be loaded like this:

```
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myjpg);
```